# Is there a way to quickly jump to a given section/chapter in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: sectioning, editors, texniccenter

Is there a way to quickly jump to a given section/chapter in TeXnicCenter?  I am coming from TeXShop on Mac, and there was a "tag" drop-down menu which had a list of all sections/chapters (as well as any comment lines which began with `%:`).  Selecting a tag from this menu scrolled immediately to the appropriate section.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. an outline is shown on the right of your main window that even displays figures, tables, etc.:

[image]

A double click on the relevant section/figure/table brings you directly to the point.

Comment: You should add, that this works only in projects! This means, also if one works with a single TeX source, for structure display creating a project is necessary.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Speravir.  That's what I needed to know.  For those who are new like me and need help creating a project from an existing file, look [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/TeXnicCenter-Users/message/2025).  (It's pretty non-obvious.)

Comment: Christian, could you please edit your answer to include a note about the necessity of working with projects?  That was the hang-up for me.  Also, is there a way to include tags which don't show up as sections?  Thanks for your help.